# TS2339(TS) Property 'touches' does not exist on type 'Event'

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2019

I'm using VS2019 and TypeScript 4.3.5.  The tsconfig.json file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "ES2017.String", "DOM", "ES2020.Intl", "ES2017" ],
    "target": "ES2017"
  }
```

points to "DOM", i.e. lib.dom.d.ts declarations file containing the touch event declarations.  Here are two (of more):

```
interface Touch {
    readonly altitudeAngle: number;
    readonly azimuthAngle: number;
    readonly clientX: number;
    readonly clientY: number;
    readonly force: number;
    readonly identifier: number;
    readonly pageX: number;
    readonly pageY: number;
    readonly radiusX: number;
    readonly radiusY: number;
    readonly rotationAngle: number;
    readonly screenX: number;
    readonly screenY: number;
    readonly target: EventTarget;
    readonly touchType: TouchType;
}
interface TouchEventInit extends EventModifierInit {
    changedTouches?: Touch[];
    targetTouches?: Touch[];
    touches?: Touch[];
}
```

Yet, when I write the following line:

```
const event: Event = window.event;
for (var i = 0; i < event.touches.length; i++);
```

I get the error:
TS2339(TS) Property 'touches' does not exist on type 'Event'.

I'm fairly new to typescript, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**`Event` is the root type of all events in `window`, other events need to inherit that event**

So there will be no `touches` property inside `Event` itself, you will need to find other extended types that has `touches` property such as `TouchEvent`

Also, `event` is a preserve name for the native window.event, try to use another name for your type.

Then your code should be like:

```
const customEvent: TouchEvent = window.event;
for (var i = 0; i < customEvent.touches.length; i++);
```

Comment: if I have to define types for typescript then there's no point in using typescript where it fails to provide the types.  Straight javascript works just fine.

Comment: Do you mean defining types for typescripts if it's not already existing it meaningless?

Comment: correct.  lib.dom.d.ts file has really good declarations that I have enjoyed using.  I was beginning to play with the touch interface and I'm getting disappointed.  Good thing is that you can have a mix of ts and js files in your project to keep them separate.

Comment: So, who do you think defines the types in lib.dom, and many other libraries? So you only want to use existing types from others but not do it by yourself? You probably get the wrong thinking about typescripts.

Comment: I didn't consider my code ending up in a published library by Microsoft.  You mean that is a possibility?

Comment: The points is… typescript is not only for library publisher but everyone. There might be a missunderstanding of you right now. I suggest that you take a look back of typescript basic purposes.